style-loader does not recoginize default imports of CSS modules in storybooks
I am setting up UI Storybooks with its newer version of 8.1.4 but could not get the style-loader and css-loader to work in a compatible way such that CSS modules can be properly loaded into the canvas of the Storybook server page.
My UI component PageHeader.tsx loads the CSS module as below:
import styles from './PageHeader.module.scss';

The ./PageHeader.module.scss module contains:
.headerContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

Once I start the storybook server, I get below exception message.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headerContainer')
    at PageHeader (http://localhost:6006/PageHeader-PageHeader-stories.iframe.bundle.js:587:89)
...

This indicates the styles object is undefined, meaning either of the loaders could not recognize that default import statement properly.
If I change the statement to import * as styles from './PageHeader.module.scss';, everything started working. But I have many UI components. I do not wish to change their syntax for the sole purpose of supporting storybooks.
The style sheet loading rule of the Webpack config in main.ts of Storybook configuration reads like below.
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: {
              mode: 'local',
              localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
            },
            importLoaders: 1,
          }
        },
        'sass-loader'
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });

And in pakcage.json, the versions of the related pakcages are:
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^8.1.4",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^8.1.4",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^8.1.4",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^8.1.4",
    "@storybook/addon-webpack5-compiler-swc": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^8.1.4",
    "@storybook/react": "^8.1.4",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^8.1.4",
    "@storybook/server-webpack5": "^8.1.4",
    "@storybook/test": "^8.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.77.0",
    "sass-loader": "^14.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0"

I have to admit that Webpack is a beast to work out on getting the right loaders for styling sheets and JavaScript/TypeScript source code. Storybooks bring that complexity to a higher level with its aggressive breaking changes across versions.

After trying many things around and researching through numerous GitHub issue posts and StackOverflow questions, I stepped out of the jungle.
I found the solution to be setting option esModule: false for the CSS loader.
The Webpack documentation page says

By default, css-loader generates JS modules that use the ES modules syntax. There are some cases in which using ES modules is beneficial, like in the case of module concatenation and tree shaking.

Syntax differences between JS and ES modules are another huge pain of compiling modern JavaScript hence I didn't dive deeper into why this worked. A quick guess is that once css-loader compiles the CSS module in CommonJS format, the style-loader becomes able to interpret the import/require statements properly.
The whole config looks like below now then.
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: {
              mode: 'local',
              localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
            },
            importLoaders: 1,
            esModule: false,
          }
        },
        'sass-loader'
      ],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });



I have been going in circles looking for problems in my webpack config. I thought I needed esModule to be true in order to import the modules using ESM syntax, but I guess that wasn't the case. Thank you!

if your tsconfig.json has "module": "esnext", try to set up esModule: false for your css-loader options
